# Hello. My program keeps failing to create the string output I expect. Can you notice a flaw?

Tags: c

This function is meant to fill a second string with the filtered results of the first. the filter should remove all special characters and only print lower case permutations of all letters written

I've tried changing the nature of the "ModifyText" loop, and I've done it with pointers+while loop and with for loops both with the condition of ending when the iterator reaches a character \0. 
These are the methods I've already tried, both continue to only return the lowercase "the" of the first word in the string, not the entire string with only lowercase alphabet letters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
//
//int ModifyText(char Stringboy[], char output[])
//{
//  for(int i=0; Stringboy[i] != '\0'; i++)
//  {
//      if(Stringboy[i] >= 'A' && Stringboy[i] <= 'Z')
//      {
//          output[i] = Stringboy[i] + 32;
//          
//      }
//      else if(Stringboy[i] >= 'a' && Stringboy[i] <= 'z')
//      {
//          output[i] = Stringboy[i];
//      }
//}}

int ModifyText(char *Stringboy, char *output)
{
    while(*Stringboy != '\0')
    {
        if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy + 32;

        }
        else if(*Stringboy >= 'a' && *Stringboy <= 'z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy;
        }
        ++Stringboy;
        ++output;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char samplearray[] = {"THE quick Brown Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog!***!"};
    char dummy[83];
    printf("Original Text: \n %s\n", samplearray);
    ModifyText(samplearray, dummy);
    printf("Modified Text: \n %s\n", dummy);
    //letterCounter(dummy); //these two bottom functions have their prints written into them, so they need only be called
    //wordCounter(dummy);

    printf("length of sample array is %d", strlen(samplearray));
}
```

This code is only returning a string "the" when it should be returning a string "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" in the string entitled dummy

Comment: You should only do ++output when you really wrote something to output

Comment: You forgot the case where a character is not a letter (numbers, spaces, special characters...)

Answer (score 1):

When *Stringboy is a space then you do not set *output since neither if condition is true.  However, you do increment output.  As a result the character after "the" in output will be random data (in your case is is probably NULL) which is why the string ends.

Change the code to this:

```
while(*Stringboy != '\0')
    {
        if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy + 32;
        }
        else 
        {
            *output = *Stringboy;
        }

        ++Stringboy;
        ++output;
    }

    *output = '\0';
```

That way the spaces will be written to the output string.

Comment: Updated answer to include null terminator

Comment: But this code does not solve the requirement to filter all characters that are not a letter,

Comment: @JohanC I'm not clear what the author means by filter all special characters.  However, the question does mention "it should be returning a string "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"" so I presume that spaces should be included.  Maybe the author would like to clarify.

Comment: @jmq since the original string contains `*`s and `!`s, and the "filtered" string does not, it seems safe to assume that they should not be included in the result.

Comment: You're correct.  I didn't scroll down enough to see the test string so I didn't realize there were other characters to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you increment the output pointer also when you didn't copy a letter. You either should write something (e.g. a space) or not increment the output pointer. If you increment the output pointer without writing something, whatever character was there before will stay there. If you're lucky that character is a zero (terminating your string), but it can also be any weird character, including character 7 (a bell sound).

Also, don't forget that your output string needs a terminating zero. Otherwise, weird uninitialized characters might pop up at the end of your string.

```
int ModifyText(char *Stringboy, char *output)
{
    while(*Stringboy != '\0')
    {
        if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy + 32;
            ++output;
        }
        else if(*Stringboy >= 'a' && *Stringboy <= 'z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy;
            ++output;
        }
        ++Stringboy;
    }
    *output = '\0';  // make sure the output gets a terminating zero
}
```

Here is a more fancy version, that outputs spaces to replace non-letters. To not get the output flooded with spaces, a boolean variable checks to maximally output one space between the words.

```
int ModifyText(char *Stringboy, char *output)
{
    bool previousWasLetter = false;
    while(*Stringboy != '\0')
    {
        if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy + 32;
            ++output;
            previousWasLetter = true;
        }
        else if(*Stringboy >= 'a' && *Stringboy <= 'z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy;
            ++output;
            previousWasLetter = true;
        }
        else if (previousWasLetter)
        {
            *output = ' ';
            ++output;
            previousWasLetter = false;
        }
        ++Stringboy;
    }
    *output = '\0';  // make sure the output gets a terminating zero
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes:

- You copy characters to a new string only if character is an uppercase letter or if the character is lowercase... but you don't copy anything, when it's not either.  As you feed the function with an array allocated in the stack (recently allocated, so probably you got a new page zero filled) the character there *could be a `\0` char* and so, delimited the string.  You need to copy the character untouched in case it's not an uppercase character... not only if it is lowercase.  This will allow you to copy the spaces (which are neither) for example.  Resulting in this code:

  ```
  if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
  {
      *output = *Stringboy + 32;
  }
  else // if(*Stringboy >= 'a' && *Stringboy <= 'z') // not needed
  {
      *output = *Stringboy;
  }
  ```
- you dont finalize the `output` string, putting a `\0` character at the end.  You should do it past the end of the loop, as the `output` pointer has been left pointing to the next output char, just add

  ```
  *output = '\0';
  ```

  next to the loop.
- Some other minor changes (these cannot be considered mistakes, but will silence some warnings got from the compiler on some permitted language inconsistencies you made), like adding a `return 0;` statement to non`void` returning functions (this should be a mistake in case you planned to return something from it), change the `%d` length format for a more portable `%zd` format string (if you have `strlen()` returning a `long` value and `int` and `long` are different size, this could lead to problems in some machines), and adding a new line `\n` character, so the shell prompt gets printed in the next line  (and not just after the string length).

So, the code finally should be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
//
//int ModifyText(char Stringboy[], char output[])
//{
//  for(int i=0; Stringboy[i] != '\0'; i++)
//  {
//      if(Stringboy[i] >= 'A' && Stringboy[i] <= 'Z')
//      {
//          output[i] = Stringboy[i] + 32;
//          
//      }
//      else if(Stringboy[i] >= 'a' && Stringboy[i] <= 'z')
//      {
//          output[i] = Stringboy[i];
//      }
//}}

int ModifyText(char *Stringboy, char *output)
{
    while(*Stringboy != '\0')
    {
        if(*Stringboy >= 'A' && *Stringboy <= 'Z')
        {
            *output = *Stringboy + 32;

        }
        else // if(*Stringboy >= 'a' && *Stringboy <= 'z') 
        {
            *output = *Stringboy;
        }
        ++Stringboy;
        ++output;
    }
    *output = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    char samplearray[] = "THE quick Brown Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog!***!"; // braces unneeded.
    char dummy[83];
    printf("Original Text: \n %s\n", samplearray);
    ModifyText(samplearray, dummy);
    printf("Modified Text: \n %s\n", dummy);
    //letterCounter(dummy); //these two bottom functions have their prints written into them, so they need only be called
    //wordCounter(dummy);

    printf("length of sample array is %zd\n", strlen(samplearray));
    return 0;
}
```